# Java 2Dimensional Boolean Array Values

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, boolean

I'm having a problem with my 2 dimensional boolean array. (or it may be with the logic of printing out the values). I set all of the values in the array to false in the beginning, and then later i print out the values to the screen. When i print them out, they all come up as true.

```
x=20;
y=10;
boolArray = new boolean[x][y];

for(int c=0;c<x;c++)
{
  for(int i=0;i<y;i++)
  {
    boolArray[c][i] = false;
  }
}

System.out.println("2D Boolean Array:");

for(int a = 0; a < boolArray.length; a++)
{
  for(int b = 0; b < boolArray[a].length; b++)
  {
    if(boolArray[a][b] = true)
    {
      System.out.print("T");
    }
    else if(boolArray[a][b] = false)
    {
      System.out.print("F");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what is value of `x` and `y`? post full code

Comment: you are using `=` in your `if` conditions, not `==`

Answer (score 1):

This is bad:

```
if(boolArray[a][b] = true)
    {
      System.out.print("T");
    }
    else if(boolArray[a][b] = false)
    {
      System.out.print("F");
    }
```

you are using the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `==`

You could change it to

```
if(boolArray[a][b] == true)
//...
else if(boolArray[a][b] == false)
```

or nicer

```
if(boolArray[a][b])
//...
else if(!boolArray[a][b])
```

or even nicer:

```
if(boolArray[a][b])
//...
else
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    if(boolArray[a][b])
    {
      System.out.print("T");
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.print("F");
    }
```

With booleans you can do like

```
if(boolean field)
```

You have used `=` assigment instead of `==` comparison.